# Laravel error in creating a table with two timestamp columns

Tags: php, eloquent, mariadb, laravel-6

I created a table in Laravel 6.6 with the following definition.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('quarters', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('quarter_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('year')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('quarter_num')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamp('valid_from');
        $table->timestamp('valid_to'); // <------ error on this line
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->primary('quarter_id');
    });
}
```

When I run the migration command I get the following error.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'valid_to' (SQL:
>   create table `quarters` (`quarter_id` int unsigned not null, `year`
>   int unsigned
>       not null, `quarter_num` int unsigned not null, `valid_from` timestamp not null, `valid_to` timestamp not null, `description`
>   varchar(255) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp
>   null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

here is the SQL generated by Eloquent:

```
CREATE TABLE `quarters`(
    `quarter_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `year` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `quarter_num` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `valid_from` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    `valid_to` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
```

The strange thing is that if I comment out the `valid_to` line then it creates the table with no error. But the definition of `valid_to` is 100% similar to `valid_from`, and it does not throw that error for the `valid_from` column. Actually it seems the DB does not allow for two`timestamp` columns!

As requested in the comments I ran the `php artisan migrate --pretend` and here is the result:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\voiceit> php artisan migrate --pretend
CreateQuartersTable: create table `quarters` (`quarter_id` int unsigned not null, `year` int unsigned not null, `quarter_num` int unsigned not null, `valid_from` timestamp not null, `valid_to` timestamp not null, `description` varchar(255) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
CreateQuartersTable: alter table `quarters` add primary key `quarters_quarter_id_primary`(`quarter_id`)
CreatePeopleDatasTable: create table `people_datas` (`mt_id` bigint unsigned not null, `valid_for` int unsigned not null, `local_personal_id` bigint unsigned not null, `first_name` varchar(255) not null, `last_name` varchar(255) not null, `date_of_birth` date null, `date_of_join` date null, `gender` varchar(1) not null, `location_type` varchar(1) not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null, `deleted_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
CreatePeopleDatasTable: alter table `people_datas` add primary key `people_datas_mt_id_valid_for_primary`(`mt_id`, `valid_for`)
CreatePeopleDatasTable: alter table `people_datas` add constraint `people_datas_valid_for_foreign` foreign key (`valid_for`) references `quarters` (`quarter_id`)
CreatePeopleDatasTable: alter table `people_datas` add constraint `people_datas_gender_foreign` foreign key (`gender`) references `genders` (`id`)
CreatePeopleDatasTable: alter table `people_datas` add constraint `people_datas_location_type_foreign` foreign key (`location_type`) references `location_types` (`id`)
CreatePeopleDatasTable: alter table `people_datas` add index `people_datas_last_name_index`(`last_name`)
```

Comment: Need to make them nullable: ` $table->timestamp('valide_to')->nullable();`

Comment: But I don't want them nullable. I need value from user. Is it some limitations from the DB? Also if this is the case why it accepts not null for `valid_from`?

Comment: This is actually a pretty weird scenario. A nullableTimestamp seems to somehow solve the issue, but it's fighting symptoms rather that finding a solution to the real problem. Could you run `php artisan migrate --pretend` and add the output to the question? It looks like Laravel might somehow create faulty SQL here, since in theory it should add a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default for SQL (see https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5b1b3675748649da19c9b6308d1ade25f41eabd5/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.php#L693 )

Comment: @Stratadox I added. Also I run the SQL statement in the PhpMyAdmin and then I received the same error: `MySQL said: #1067 - Invalid default value for 'valid_to'`. It seems it is a wrong SQL or a limitation from the DB.

Comment: Which Mysql version are you using? It looks like the explicit_defaults_for_timestamp setting might be causing this problem: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

Comment: More info on this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: @Stratadox Here you go: 
`Server version: 10.4.6-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution`

Comment: I solved my issue by changing the type of the column from `timestamp` to `dateTime` so changing the table definition to `$table->dateTime('valid_from');             $table->dateTime('valid_to');` solved my issue as I need a date and a time, but still I am interested to know how can we have multiple not nullable timestamp columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my issue by changing the type of the column from `timestamp` to `dateTime`. So changing the table definition as follow solved my issue as I need a date and a time:

```
Schema::create('quarters', function (Blueprint $table) {
             $table->integer('quarter_id')->unsigned();
             $table->integer('year')->unsigned();
             $table->integer('quarter_num')->unsigned();
             $table->dateTime('valid_from');
             $table->dateTime('valid_to');            
             $table->string('description')->nullable();
             $table->timestamps();
             $table->primary('quarter_id');
        });
```

However, I am still interested to know how can we have multiple `not null` timestamp columns in a table.

Comment: this is better approach rather than timestamp

Answer (score 4):

The default behaviour for default values of timestamps in MySql and/or MariaDB is different for the first timestamp declaration than for subsequent timestamps.

> MariaDB has special behavior for the first column that uses the TIMESTAMP data type in a specific table. For the first column that uses the TIMESTAMP data type in a specific table, MariaDB automatically assigns the following properties to the column:
>
> DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
>      ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
>
> This means that if the column is not explicitly assigned a value in an INSERT or UPDATE query, then MariaDB will automatically initialize the column's value with the current date and time.
>
> This automatic initialization for INSERT and UPDATE queries can also be explicitly enabled for a column that uses the TIMESTAMP data type by specifying the DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP clauses for the column. In these clauses, any synonym of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is accepted, including CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), NOW(), LOCALTIME, LOCALTIME(), LOCALTIMESTAMP, and LOCALTIMESTAMP().

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/timestamp/

Ergo, the first timestamp (`valid_from`) gets the automatic default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, which is an acceptable default value for non-nullable timestamp fields. The second field gets a different automatic default value, which appears to be unacceptable to the database.

A solution to the immediate problem might be to follow MariaDB's suggestion and use an explicit `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default for the second timestamp (or both, while at it).
In Laravel terms, this is probably something like `$table->timestamp('valid_to')->useCurrent();`.

Important to notice in this regard, is that the solution you seem to have chosen in the end (using datetime over timestamp) is probably a more apt solution to the problem: timestamps are somewhat weird data types that are mainly used as meta-data only. Especially in Mysql and MariaDB, they inherently suffer from the ["Year 2038 problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem), which isn't a problem for created_at or updated_at fields for another 18 years or so, but might be problematic when the valid_to can be some years in the future. And that's only in addition to the unintuitive automatic default values...

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it add or modify  the server variable "explicit-defaults-for-timestamp"... You need set it to ON

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32615069)

Comment: Maybe be a little more specific , ie. "modify the MySQL server variable EXPLICIT_DEFAULTS"